# how eclipse know my attach source folder

Tags: eclipse, configuration

how eclipse know my source code folder when I associate it if I associate it last time.
and if I want to change another folder how can I do,I think there is a file save all my 
setting configs. and I just simple modify it.but where and what it is?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is able to automatically find the `src` folder for your project because it is defined in the Eclipse `.classpath` file in your project's root directory.

To change the `src` folder for your project, do the following:

- Select a project in the Eclipse workspace and right click to bring up the context menu
- Choose *Properties*
- Choose *Java Build Path*
- Select the *Source* tab. Here, you can *Edit*, *Link*, *Remove*, and *Create* source folders

Comment: thanks,and I have know that eclipse save the properties in               workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\.indexes>properties.index ,and I can't modify it manually,this file is not a plain text.^_^